# extracting a data from a RDD like json object with spark

Tags: java

I am looking to extract the `title` from this json using Spark.

data:

```
{
   "bot":false,
   "comment":"",
   "id":null,
   "log_action":"hit",
   "log_action_comment":"186.4.62.192 disparÃ³ [[Especial:FiltroAntiAbusos/84|filtro 84]] al realizar la acciÃ³n Â«editÂ» en [[Club Sport Herediano]]. Medidas adoptadas: Etiquetar ([[Especial:RegistroAbusos/8302091|detalles]])",
   "log_id":0,
   "log_params":{
      "action":"edit",
      "actions":"tag",
      "filter":84,
      "log":8302091
   },
   "log_type":"abusefilter",
   "meta":{
      "domain":"es.wikipedia.org",
      "dt":"2017-12-26T14:26:19+00:00",
      "id":"bd2f1911-ea48-11e7-9940-1866da99511e",
      "request_id":"8575a568-0d89-4934-a82d-bf75a9cf4b57",
      "schema_uri":"mediawiki/recentchange/1",
      "topic":"eqiad.mediawiki.recentchange",
      "uri":"https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Club_Sport_Herediano",
      "partition":0,
      "offset":617123484
   },
   "namespace":0,
   "parsedcomment":"",
   "server_name":"es.wikipedia.org",
   "server_script_path":"/w",
   "server_url":"https://es.wikipedia.org",
   "timestamp":1514298379,
   "title":"Club Sport Herediano",
   "type":"log",
   "user":"186.4.62.192",
   "wiki":"eswiki"
}
```

thanks for helping me .

Comment: what `spark` is this about? apache spark or sparkjava (http://sparkjava.com/)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.